# Set recipient in Composite Template

Tags: docusignapi

I use Foxit Phantom for pre-fill tabs to documents. I use PDF form with label DocuSignSignHere. But, How to set recipient using this technique?
https://www.docusign.com/p/APIGuide/Content/Sending%20Group/Rules%20for%20CompositeTemplate%20Usage.htm

I tried to set number after label: DocuSignSignHere 1, DocuSignSignHere 2. It does not work. Is it possible? How to set recipientID with PDF Form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In our way solution was in using [Automatic Anchor Text with Custom Tags](https://www.docusign.com/support/salesforce/documentation/dfs-admin-guide/admin-guide/use-automatic-anchor-text-with-custom-tags)

Answer (score 0):

You can not set DocuSign recipient information through the PDF fields of the document you want to get signed.  Instead you need to set that information in the API call you make to DocuSign, inside the JSON properties of your request body.

Here is a full code sample (in 6 languages) of how to request a signature on a local document:

http://iodocs.docusign.com/APIWalkthrough/requestSignatureFromDocument

And make sure you check out the other 8 API Walkthroughs [here](http://iodocs.docusign.com/apiwalkthroughs).